# how to get a panel within a set height parent wrapper to scroll not change the parent's height at the same time

Tags: css, scroll, height

I am trying to set the height of a child so that what ever extra comes in would set the overflow to scroll, but not affect the parent's height;

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/oppbktLb/2/

-- updated url --

http://jsfiddle.net/x3azn/oppbktLb/5/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">Header</div>
    <div class="menu">Menu</div>
    <div class="content">This is content, it should be flexible, dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj dsfasdflkasjdfl;kajs;fdlkasj</div>
</div>
```

css portion:

```
.wrapper{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    /* It needs to be this
    overflow: hidden; scroll the yellow part (content instead)
     */}
.header{
    background: green;
}
.menu{
    background: red;
}
.content{
    background: yellow;
}
```

so in this example, i am trying to make the yellow portion scrollable without affecting the height of the entire box at the same time. no calculations with javascript, fixed position。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it seems to do what I think you are looking for.

```
.wrapper{
border: 1px solid black;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
overflow:hidden;
/* It needs to be this
overflow: hidden; scroll the yellow part (content instead)
 */}
.header{
    background: green;
}
.menu{
    background: red;
}
.content{
    background: yellow;
    height:100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oppbktLb/6/